# Coercion making a problem in arithmetic operations

Tags: r, class, dataframe, character, coercion

I have introduced some **character values** in *mtcars dataset*. The class of variables become character due to **coercion**.

My requirement is to get numeric values as numeric class and let the character values stay in their actual form i.e character class. So that i don't face a problem in doing calculations.

I tried **as.numeric(as.character(data))** as well but it converts character values to NA.

I'm currently getting results for variables like 'abc' 'dcb' '4' '2' '6'.

But i need something like following:  **abc dcb 4 2 6**

Can somebody please figure it out. I shall be extremely thankful.

My codes are as follows:

```
bb<-rep(x = 'abc', times=11)
cc<-rep(x = 'dcb', times=11)
mtcars[1,]<-bb
mtcars[2,]<-cc
```

Comment: You can store it in a  `list` as it can have different type.  A `vector` can have only a single type.  If there is a single character element, it gets converted to that type.  So, perhaps `l1 <- list(c(1, 2, 6), "apple")`

Comment: Thanks. What if i got a data set (e.g mtcars) with first three rows as characters and remaining rows in numeric form? This is my more related to my actual problem

Comment: I have updated my codes. pls have a look. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As list stores multiple types, if u check for numeric and get the values of the vector as numeric.

```
list_data = sapply(data,function(x) {if(is.numeric(x))as.numeric(x)})
```

Comment: Thanks. What if i got a data set (e.g mtcars) with first three rows as characters and remaining rows in numeric form? This is my more related to my actual problem

Comment: is.numeric(x) will be false for any string or character, you'd need to make something more like if(is.numeric(as.numeric(as.character(x)))){x}else{as.character(x)} but you'd still get an NA warning

Comment: !is.na(as.numeric(x)) would do

Comment: I dont think u can have a vector that has few elements as char and few number, use a list instead as suggested.

Comment: !is.na(as.numeric(x))  it removes the character value, i want the character value to stay as it is

Comment: The list function doesn't work on updated mtcars data